# Maintaining Layout of Percentage-Based Children in React Native Reanimated Wrapper

Tags: react-native, layout, wrapper, react-functional-component

I'm working on a wrapper component that should animate child components using `React Native Reanimated`.

My current approach is to clone each child and wrap it into a `Animated.View`.

```js
export function AnimationWrapper(props){
    const alphas = [];
    
    function createAnimatedStyle(sharedValue) {
        return useAnimatedStyle(() => {
            return {
                transform: [{translateY: -sharedValue.value * 255}],
                opacity: 1 - Math.abs(sharedValue.value),
            };
        })
    }
    
    function renderChildren(){
        return props.children
            .map((child, index) => {
                if(!child) return null;
                alphas.push(useSharedValue(-1));
                return(
                    <Animated.View key={index} style={[createAnimatedStyle(alphas[alphas.length-1])]}>
                        {React.cloneElement(child)}
                    </Animated.View>
                );
            });
    }

//Later we can animate the alphas array...

    return({renderChildren()});
}
```

This works well if the children have absolute sizes.
My challenge is maintaining the layout of child components that have percentage-based width and height.
The `<Animated.View>` component adjusts its size to the child. So if we try to make the width/height of the child relative by using percentage, the width/height will result in 0.

From a layout point of view I want the Child to ignore the `Animated.View` wrapper and adjust its layout to the grandparent. So even if my Functional Component wraps each child, the layout should stay the same.

So how can I maintain the layout of child components with percentage-based dimensions inside an `Animated.View` in `React Native Reanimated`? Or are there other ways to animate my children?

Comment: Why you don't give the wrapper the percentage width/height?

Comment: Because my „Animation Wrapper“ is supposed to be used universally. 
The issue here is, that some Style properties would need to be applied to the wrapper and some to the child. Let me elaborate: let’s say I am using percentage based width, so I hard code my wrapper to apply the width, and remove it from the child. 
But I also use a flex property. This fundamentally changes the logic, so I also need to apply this to the wrapper. In addition I use a fontSize property because I am wrapping a text. I need to apply that to the child. So basically one would need to hard code all properties.

Comment: to either apply to the wrapper or to the child. Which is not maintainable